# Laravel How to get Url

Tags: laravel, url, pagination

When trying to get page url with

```
URL::current();
```

it's ignore the pagination. 
For example:

current url is `www.google.com/searc?page=2`

```
dd(URL::current());
```

gives us `www.google.com/search`. Using default pagination.

My question is: Any function for get url with paginations?

Comment: `dd(URL::full());` ?

Comment: yes this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the full URL, not just the URL. Try this:

```
\URL::full();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use :

`\URL::full();`

It will give the url along with query string.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls) of Laraval. You can use `URL::full()`

> Accessing The Current URL
>
> If no path is provided to the url helper, a
>   Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator instance is returned, allowing you to
>   access information about the current URL:

```
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();

// Get the current URL including the query string...
echo url()->full();

// Get the full URL for the previous request...
echo url()->previous();
```

> Each of these methods may also be accessed via the URL facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

echo URL::current();
```